# Popup doesn't display in unlocked achievements

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm having an issue displaying popups for unlocked achievements.

I have looked around on SO but didn't find a solution that solved my specific problem.

I have the following code in my MainActivity:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.id_oauth_web_client)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content)) 
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .build();

// Unlock a test achievement just starting the app
Games.getAchievementsClient(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .unlockImmediate(getString(R.string.ach_test));
```

The code is executed with no problem, but the popup doesn't appear.

The welcome back popup is shown perfectly and if I check the achievements list I can see it is unlocked.

What am I missing?